# Function not declared when it is VBA

Tags: excel, vba, function

Hi when I run the code I get the "Not sub or function declared" when it's, I have 3 functions and the error just happens with this one

```vb
Public Function atleastOne(ParamArray params() As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim checked As Boolean
    For Each param In params
        If param.Caption = Char(254) Then
            checked = True
    Next
    
    If checked Then
        MsqBox "Tiene que seleccionar una opción", "Error"
        atleastOne = False
    Else
        atleastOne = True
    End If
End Function
```

and I call the function here

```vb
Private Sub toPreg2_Click()
    Dim isSelected As Boolean
    isSelected = atleastOne(op1A, op1B, op1C, op1D, op1E)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three issues I see right off bat

- `Char` is not a function within VBA. What you are probably trying is `Chr`
- `MsqBox` should be `Msgbox`
- and you are missing and `End If` statement in your first conditional.

```vb
Public Function atleastOne(ParamArray params() As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim checked As Boolean
    For Each param In params
        If param.Caption = Chr(254) Then ' `Chr` vs `Char`
            checked = True
        End If  ' Was missing
    Next
    
    If checked Then
        MsgBox "Tiene que seleccionar una opción", "Error" ' `Msgbox` vs `MsqBox`
        atleastOne = False
    Else
        atleastOne = True
    End If
End Function

Private Sub toPreg2_Click()
    Dim isSelected As Boolean
    isSelected = atleastOne(op1A, op1B, op1C, op1D, op1E)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for answering, yes, it was the 'Char vs Chr' sorry for my dumb question, again, thank you!